# jsonReader 'page' not working in jqGrid

Tags: jqgrid

I'm using `jqGrid` in which i have a `jsonReader` property and inside that i'm using a function to show the `pager` of the grid.

My `jsonReader` page function is working when the grid binds some records. Its not getting called when the grid binds no records. But i have to disable the `pager(Previous/Last)` when the grid binds no records. Any ideas why?

//Code:

```js
$("#AttachmentsGrid").jqGrid({
    url: '@Url.Action("LoadTransactionAttachments", "Home")',
    postData: { 'transactionId': selectedRowId },
    ajaxGridOptions: { contentType: "application/json" },
    hoverrows: false,
    datatype: 'json',
    hidegrid: false,
    rowList: [10, 20, 30],
    rownumbers: true,
    viewrecords: true,
    height: 'auto',
    gridview: true,
    autoencode: true,
    autowidth: true,
    shrinkToFit: false,
    rowNum: 10,
    pager: '#AttachmentsPager',
    caption: "Attachments",
    colNames: ['AttachmentName'],
    colModel: [{ name: 'AttachmentName', index: 'AttachmentName' }],
    jsonReader: {
        repeatitems: false,
        id: 'AttachmentId',
        page: function (obj) {
          //Not working
            if (obj.length == 0) {
                return "0";
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Any help?

Comment: Which response exactly returns the server "when the grid binds no records"? Could you use Developer Tools of Internet Explorer/Chrome/Firefox or tool like [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/download/fiddler) to examine HTTP traffic?

Comment: @Oleg: Sorry, was out of town.I'm getting "[]" as the response when the records are none. This gets bind to the grid.